# nth derivative of a symmetric function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

im triying to demonstrate that π is irrational and at a point in the proof it is asked to prove that $  f^n(1) = 0  $    for the function:

$f = \frac{x^n(1 - x)^n}{ n!}$

This function verifies that $\operatorname{f}(x)$ = $\operatorname{f}(1-x)$ so by symmetry we obtain that $f^n(x) = (-1)^nf^n(1 - x)$.

What is the reason why that is its derivative?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
 f(x) &= f(1-x)\\
f'(x) &= -\dfrac{df(1-x)}{dx}=f'(1-x)\cdot \dfrac{d(1-x)}{dx}=(-1)^1f'(1-x)\\
f''(x) &= \dfrac{df'(1-x)}{dx}=-f''(1-x)\cdot\dfrac{d(1-x)}{dx}=(-1)^2f''(1-x)\\
&\cdots\quad \cdots\quad\cdots\\
f^n(x) &= (-1)^nf(1-x)\\
\end{align}

Comment: well, im dumb, ty :D

Comment: these are some elementary calculations. Hope you're good with this!!

Comment: yeah, i got it, just that was actually a dumb question hahaha ><